# read file and construct facts in prolog

Tags: prolog

I would like to construct a mechanism that constructs different facts depending from txt file,
imported in prolog. I already have found some examples where they directly assert the line that was read from the file, but I have to transform the data before assertion can take place.

To give an example:

```
man = {m1, m2}.

m1: w1 > w2.
```

should be read as:

```
man(m1).
man(m2).
prefer(m1, w1, 1).
prefer(m1, w2, 2).
```

Is it possible to construct these facts based on the symbols of the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to the fact that data presented in example is valid Prolog syntax, this code will do

```
load_file_data(File) :-
    open(File, read, Stream),
    repeat,
    read(Stream, Term),
    (   Term = end_of_file
    ->  true
    ;   process(Term),
        fail
    ),
    close(Stream).

process(X = {L}) :-
    forall(arg(_, L, A), (F =.. [X, A], assert(F))).
process(X : A > B) :-
    assert(prefer(X, A, 1)),
    assert(prefer(X, B, 2)).
```

note that the precedence of operators in `m1: w1 > w2` is not what we could expect, but it works anyway, thanks to complete pattern matching. Use

```
?- write_canonical(m1 : w1 > w2).
>(:(m1,w1),w2)
```

to check precedence when not sure.

Comment: oops, I wasn't paying close attention - yup, CapelliC's right, you can do it all with operator definitions.

Answer (score 4):

yes - you need to do what you'd do in any other language.

Open and read the file, parse the contents, and convert into terms that you can then assert.

Fortunately, you're in prolog, so 'parse the contents' is a task the language does for breakfast.

It turns out I've been writing a tutorial on how to do pretty much this exact task.
It's not quite finished, but is online at

http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/dcg/

If your files are large, use the method described in the tutorial to read them. Otherwise, just bring the file into a 'codes' style string and go on with life.

Comment: can you please give the gist of how to do this with a gdc? Because Iven gone through your tutorial and don't see how to assert new rules from a file.

Comment: adding another answer, comment area not big enough

Comment: Please don't leave link only answers. Also as Jan noted, thanks for your effort in promoting Prolog. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do any 'normal' prolog in a DCG by enclosing it in {}

some_nonterminal  -->
         "fridge", 
         blanks,
         [X],
         {
              % you can put any normal Prolog code in here
              assert(fridge_named(X))
         }.

This looks for a sequence like

fridge G

and asserts fridge_named(0x47) in the database (Ascii G is 0x47)

Comment: but what I want is to add an atom to the database so when I have :

    some_nonterminal --> "fridge", blanks, atom(X), 
    { assert(fridge_named(X)) }.

Nothing is added ... how come?

Comment: show a complete sample.  I suspect you're not defining blanks, or not calling phrase properly or something.  You can also put a writeln in the {} to prove you're getting there

Comment: what I want is to bind my X to an atom instead of a string. Then assert the "name of the fridge" as an atom.

Comment: atom_codes(AFridge, StringFridge), assert(fridge_named(AFridge)).